# Finding objects in a list by an attribute

Tags: python, list, object

I have the following code.  I am trying to create a list of objects, then have user input the name or an attribute of the object they would like to find, so they can find that object in their inventory.  Thanks

```
import Game
import sys
import os
import time
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass

#constructor = name, ability, hitpoints, attack, gold, potions

def main():
    lst=[]
    c1 = Game.Character('j', "Forcefield", 100, 10, 0, 0)
    lst.append(c1)
    c2 = Game.Character("Sue", "Jump", 100, 10, 0, 0)
    lst.append(c2)

    x = input("Enter the name of the character to search for")

    for i in lst:
        if i == x:
            print("found")  


main()
```

Comment: The problem is, nothing is printing. I think the problem is that i is iterating over the list, which contains objects.  For some reason, it's not searching by the name entered.  So this means that the object is stored as a different name other than "character1 or character2" in the list... soo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare the input with the attribute of the instance.

```
for i in lst:
    if i.name == x:
        print("found")
```

Comment: Ernest, Thank you.  This fixed the problem.. By the way - do you think that this is the best way for me to create a list of objects, just appending them one at a time?  What I would really like to do is have an object added to a pre-existing list once the object is instantiated.  Is there a way you know of to do this?  Thanks again.  J

Comment: Appending the list after the object is created seems to be the nice and easy way.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over `lst` would give you `Game.Character` objects in `i` in each iteration. Instead of `i == x`, use `i.name == x`